# Webservice Wants Byte[] - How do I send that from PHP?

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I've got a webservice written in c#, which accepts as a parameter an array of bytes (byte[]). I'm trying to consume the service using PHP, but am having problems getting the parameter to the correct type expected by the webservice.

Anyone know how this is accomplished?

Comment: What does the byte[] represent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send the data as base64 encoded data. This will get converted to a `byte[]` by C#.

You can use `base64_encode` to do this in PHP.

Comment: Good call. Looking at the WSDL for a function with a return type of byte[], the response type is: type="s:base64Binary"